# Как в PyQt5 менять шрифт в тексте кнопки?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qfont, qfontdatabase

Мне нужно чтобы в текстах (кнопки) менялся шрифт на тот, который я указываю (в моем случае на **Pusia-Bold.ttf**).

Мой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

try:
    from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QtWin
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass


class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        def Button(btn_name, text, color1, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: " + color1 + "; color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px;}QPushButton:pressed {background-image: url(image/img2.1.png) }")
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            #btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_2(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            #btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_3(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Image(lbl_name, move_1, move_2, resize_1, resize_2):
            lbl_name.setPixmap(self.pix)
            lbl_name.move(move_1, move_2)
            lbl_name.resize(resize_1, resize_2)

        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
        Image(self.lbl2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("textbox.png")
        Image(self.lbl1, 0, 750, 1920, 300)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_2(self.btn1, "Вы появились в неизвестном вам месте,\nгде было невероятно красиво", 10, 1000, 100, 430, 810, "White")
        self.btn3 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_2(self.btn3, "", 10, 150, 100, -30, 500, "White")
        self.inv = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory_btn.png")
        Image(self.inv, -30, 600, 156, 96)
        self.btn31 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn31, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 600, "White", self.inventory)
        self.inv_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory.png")
        Image(self.inv_open, 50, 0, 1770, 996)
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn4, "", 5, 100, 100, 1650, 60, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn4.close()
        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Selection_menu.png")
        Image(self.lbl2, 0, -70, 1920, 1080)
        self.lbl2.close()
        self.mg_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/Magazine.png")
        Image(self.mg_open, -30, 480, 156, 96)
        self.btn5 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn5, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 480, "White", self.event_log)
        self.btn6 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn6, "", 0, 460, 800, 160, 100, "White", self.notes)
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn7, "", 0, 460, 800, 700, 100, "White", self.easter)
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn8, "", 0, 460, 800, 1260, 100, "White", self.tasks)
        self.btn8.close()
        self.notes_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Notes.png")
        Image(self.notes_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn9, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn9.close()
        self.easter_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Easter.png")
        Image(self.easter_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn10, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn10.close()

        self.tasks_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Tasks.png")
        Image(self.tasks_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn11 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn11, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn11.close()

    def inventory(self):
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.inv_open.show()
        self.btn4.show()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

    def inventory_close(self):
        self.btn3.show()
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()

    def animations(self):
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        animation.setTargetObject(self.btn_name)
        animation.setPropertyName(b'pos')
        animation.setStartValue(QPoint(250, -200))
        animation.setEndValue(QPoint(250, 0))
        animation.setDuration(500)
        animation.start()

    def event_log(self):
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn3.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.lbl2.show()
        self.btn6.show()
        self.btn7.show()
        self.btn8.show()

    def notes(self):
        self.lbl2.close()
        self.notes_open.show()
        self.btn9.show()

    def easter(self):
        self.lbl2.close()
        self.easter_open.show()
        self.btn10.show()

    def tasks(self):
        self.lbl2.close()
        self.tasks_open.show()
        self.btn11.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(1920, 1080)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Story Telling')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, я не могу воспроизвести ваш пример.

Да и **Pusia-Bold.ttf** - у меня тоже нету.
Но у меня есть **`Roboto Fonts`** и вот как я предложу вам
попробовать вставлять нужный вам `Font` для текста кнопки.

```
import glob
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
names = []

for path in glob.glob("D:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Font/Fonts/Roboto/*.ttf"):
    names.append(os.path.basename(path.replace(".ttf", "")).replace("-", ""))
    fid = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(os.path.abspath(path))

w = QWidget()
w.setWindowTitle("Roboto Fonts")
layout = QGridLayout(w)

for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        layout.addWidget(
            QPushButton(
                names[row * 4 + col],
                font=QFont(names[row * 4 + col], 16)
            ),    
            row, col, 1, 1
        )

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> но в таком случае мне дает ошибку: 
> "names[row * 4 + col], IndexError: list index out of range"
>
> `print(* names, sep='\n')`, мне выводит название моего шрифта.

---

```
import glob
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
names = []

for path in glob.glob("D:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Font/Fonts/Roboto/*.ttf"):
    names.append(os.path.basename(path.replace(".ttf", "")).replace("-", ""))
    fid = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(os.path.abspath(path))

print(* names, sep='\n') #

w = QWidget()
w.setWindowTitle("Roboto Fonts")
layout = QGridLayout(w)

layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
    names[0],
    font=QFont(names[0], 16)
))

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: но в таком случае мне дает ошибку "names[row * 4 + col],
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @TFader я же вам все показал как оно у меня. 16 файлов `*.ttf`, которые я размещаю 4х4. Как оно у вас я не знаю.

Comment: @TFader   вставьте  `print(* names, sep='\n')`    перед `w = QWidget()` и посмотрите, что у вас там.

Comment: Мне выводит название моего шрифта

Comment: @TFader я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

try:
    from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QtWin
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass
class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        def Button(btn_name, text, color1, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "background-color: " + color1 + "; color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px;}QPushButton:pressed {background-image: url(image/img2.1.png) }")
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            #btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)
        def Button_2(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.setFont(QFont('Pusia Extra Bold', 20))
            #btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)
        def Button_3(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)
        def Image(lbl_name, move_1, move_2, resize_1, resize_2):
            lbl_name.setPixmap(self.pix)
            lbl_name.move(move_1, move_2)
            lbl_name.resize(resize_1, resize_2)

        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg")
        Image(self.lbl2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("textbox.png")
        Image(self.lbl1, 0, 750, 1920, 300)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_2(self.btn1, "Вы появились в неизвестном вам месте,\nгде было невероятно красиво", 10, 1000, 100, 430, 810, "White")
        self.btn3 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_2(self.btn3, "", 10, 150, 100, -30, 500, "White")
        self.inv = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory_btn.png")
        Image(self.inv, -30, 600, 156, 96)
        self.btn31 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn31, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 600, "White", self.inventory)
        self.inv_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory.png")
        Image(self.inv_open, 50, 0, 1770, 996)
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn4, "", 5, 100, 100, 1650, 60, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn4.close()
        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Selection_menu.png")
        Image(self.lbl2, 0, -70, 1920, 1080)
        self.lbl2.close()
        self.mg_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/Magazine.png")
        Image(self.mg_open, -30, 480, 156, 96)
        self.btn5 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn5, "", 0, 100, 100, 0, 480, "White", self.event_log)
        self.btn6 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn6, "", 0, 460, 800, 160, 100, "White", self.notes)
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn7, "", 0, 460, 800, 700, 100, "White", self.easter)
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn8, "", 0, 460, 800, 1260, 100, "White", self.tasks)
        self.btn8.close()
        self.notes_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Notes.png")
        Image(self.notes_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn9, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn9.close()
        self.easter_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Easter.png")
        Image(self.easter_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn10, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn10.close()

        self.tasks_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Tasks.png")
        Image(self.tasks_open, 0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn11 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn11, "", 5, 80, 80, 1730, 50, "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn11.close()

    def inventory(self):
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.inv_open.show()
        self.btn4.show()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()
    def inventory_close(self):
        self.btn3.show()
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()
    def animations(self):
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        animation.setTargetObject(self.btn_name)
        animation.setPropertyName(b'pos')
        animation.setStartValue(QPoint(250, -200))
        animation.setEndValue(QPoint(250, 0))
        animation.setDuration(500)
        animation.start()
    def event_log(self):
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn3.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.lbl2.show()
        self.btn6.show()
        self.btn7.show()
        self.btn8.show()
    def notes(self):
        self.lbl2.close()
        self.notes_open.show()
        self.btn9.show()
    def easter(self):
        self.lbl2.close()
        self.easter_open.show()
        self.btn10.show()
    def tasks(self):
        self.lbl2.close()
        self.tasks_open.show()
        self.btn11.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('Pusia Extra Bold.ttf')
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(1920, 1080)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Story Telling')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))

    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Я только учусь, только так смог.

Comment: Проблема в том, что он не меняется

Comment: QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('Pusia Extra Bold.ttf') а файл для импорта шрифта добавляете в папку? Я у себя проверял у меня работает.

Comment: Да, я добавил название (Pusia-Bold.ttf)

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня вроде вот получается, по умолчанию в Qt нету такого шрифта, приходится импортировать из файла